# Populating a spreadsheet from other tab values

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel for Mac:

I have 2 tabs (wkst1 and wkst2) and need to populate a third one (wkst3)

wkst1 has one column with names listed
e.g.

```
A

B
```

wkst2 has two columns

```
X     1

Y     4
```

I need to populate wkst3 to ensure all rows in wkst2 are associated to each name listed in wkst1.

e.g. my wished result would be:

```
A     X     1

A     Y     4

B     X     1

B     Y     4
```

Can you suggest the code I should use?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem on my own.

```
Sub writeall()

    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim Ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim Ws2 As Worksheet

    Dim X As Long
    Dim Y As Long
    Dim count As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set Ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set Ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
    Set Ws2 = Workbooks("xxxx.xlsx").Sheets("2017") ' xxxx is the name of the xlsx

    count = 1

    For X = 2 To Ws2.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
        For Y = 1 To Ws1.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
            count = count + 1
            Ws.Cells(count, 1).Value = Ws2.Cells(X, 1).Value
            Ws.Cells(count, 2).Value = Ws1.Cells(Y, 2).Value
            Ws.Cells(count, 3).Value = Ws1.Cells(Y, 1).Value

        Next Y
    Next X

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox ("Spreadsheet updated")

End Sub
```